# How can I prevent requests.Response.iter_content() from repeatedly printing the chunk size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm using requests to download a response like so:

```py
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)

# to local file
with open(valid_filename, "wb") as file_writer:
    for chunk in resp.iter_content(1024):
        file_writer.write(chunk)

# to google bucket blob
blob = gs_bucket.blob(filename)
with blob.open("wb") as blob_writer:
    for chunk in resp.iter_content(1024):
        blob_writer.write(chunk)
```

Both of these methods cause the chunk_size (1024) to be repeatedly output while the response is being iterated over.

```py
>>> with open(r"C:\Users\me\Downloads\xl_resp.xlsx", "wb") as file_writer:
    for chunk in xl_resp.iter_content(1024):
        file_writer.write(chunk)
        
1024
1024
...
1024
471

>>> with blob.open("wb") as blob_writer:
    for chunk in resp.iter_content(1024):
        blob_writer.write(chunk)

1024
1024
...
1024
471
```

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Are you running those code snipptets in the interactive interpreter provided by an IDE? Because that looks like return values from the `write` calls, which are being printed by an  overenthusiastic REPL, not anything from `iter_content` itself. I don't think the normal REPL does that (expression statements in loops have their return values ignored, only the results of top-level expression statements get printed).

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense! Yes, this was from the IDLE packaged with the python installation. I was just running some tests before deciding how to implement some logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers you're seeing printed out are not being printed by any of your own code. Rather, they're the values being `return`ed by the `write` calls you are making in the loop.

The output won't show up if you run your code as a script, and even in most interactive sessions, you won't see them either. However, the IDLE IDE that is packaged with Python has an unusually aggressive REPL (Read, Eval, Print Loop). It doesn't only print out the results of expression statements at the top level (the way the normal Python interactive interpreter behaves). It *also* prints out the values of expression statements that occur in loops like yours.

If you need to run this code in IDLE and don't want the output, you could assign the return values to some variable:

```
bytes_written = file_writer.write(chunk)
```

But if you're not going to be using IDLE when you run this code "for real", you can simply ignore the output for now. It won't be printed if you run the code as a script (not even from within IDLE's editor).